# ffmpeg : scroll smoothly an image and text in a defined area

Tags: ffmpeg

I know how to scroll a picture from the bottom to the top of a video using this command :

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1920x1080 -loop 1 -t 0.08 -i "input.jpg" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=1920:-2,setpts=if(eq(N\,0)\,0\,1+1/0.02/TB),fps=25[fg]; [0:v][fg]overlay=y=-\'t*h*0.02\':eof_action=endall[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

But I want the image and the text starts appearing from a position in bottom and scroll smoothly and disappear in a position in top like in the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may crop the relevant region from the background image, overlay the scrolled text over the cropped region, and overlay the result to the same region in the background image.

---

Example:

`bk.jpg`:
Background image - prepared from advance:
[image]

`input.jpg`:
Foreground image - prepared from advance (sample resolution is 270x257):
[image]

---

Sample command:

`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -r 25 -i bk.jpg -loop 1 -r 25 -i input.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=270:257:360:55[c0];[c0][1:v]overlay=y='257-t*257*0.04':eof_action=endall[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=x=360:y=55:eof_action=endall" -t 50 output.mp4`

---

- `[0:v]crop=270:257:360:55[c0]` - crops 270x257 region from the background.
- `[c0][1:v]overlay=y='257-t*257*0.04':eof_action=endall[fg]` - overlays the scrolled text over the cropped region.
- `[0:v][fg]overlay=x=360:y=55:eof_action=endall` - overlays `[fg]` over the background image (at the same place of the cropped region).

---

Downscaled result:
[image]

Comment: Your idea is working